# Removing specific tuples from List

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've got a list

```
a = [(1,2),(1,4),(2,6),(1,8),(3,6),(1,10),(1,6)]
```

If I say that:

```
for x in a:
    if x[0]==1:
        print x
```

I get the expected result : (1,2) (1,4) (1,8) (1,10) (1,6)

However I want to remove all the occurrences of all the tuples in the format (1,x),So

```
for x in a:
   if x[0]==1:
       a.remove(x)
```

I thought that all the occurences should be removed.However when i say

```
Print a
```

I get [(1,4),(2,6),(3,6),(1,6)]

Not all the tuples were removed. How do I do it.??
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def removeTuplesWithOne(lst):
    return [x for x in lst if x[0] != 1]

a = removeTuplesWithOne([(1,2),(1,4),(2,6),(1,8),(3,6),(1,10),(1,6)])
```

For me it's more pythonic than built-in `filter` function.

P.S. This function does not change your original list, it creates new one. If your original list is huge, i'd probably use [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) like so:

```
def removeTuplesWithOne(lst):
    return (x for x in lst if x[0] != 1)
```

Comment: this one is better solution

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the same approach as yours but should work

```
a = filter(lambda x: x[0] != 1, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) like this, to filter out the items which have `1` as the first element.

```
>>> original = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 6), (1, 8), (3, 6), (1, 10), (1, 6)]
>>> [item for item in original if item[0] != 1]
[(2, 6), (3, 6)]
```

This creates a new list, rather than modifying the existing one. 99% of the time, this will be fine, but if you *need* to modify the original list, you can do that by assigning back:

```
original[:] = [item for item in original if item[0] != 1]
```

Here we use slice assignment, which works by replacing every item from the start to the end of the original list (the `[:]`) with the items from the list comprehension. If you just used normal assignment, you would just change what the name `original` pointed to, not actually modify the list itself.

Comment: but i think, he wants to delete from list. does your code delete them from list?

Comment: You can always assign back to the original if modifying the original list is actually needed (99% of the time it won't be). `original[:] = new`. I've edited for a little formatting and to add that explanation.

Comment: And the reason for downvoting would be?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) expression if you're dealing with huge amounts of data:

```
a = [(1,2),(1,4),(2,6),(1,8),(3,6),(1,10),(1,6)]

# create a generator
a = ((x,y) for x, y in a if x == 1)

# simply convert it to a list if you need to...
>>> print list(a)
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 8), (1, 10), (1, 6)]
```